# Why do American farmers buy tractors from John Deere?

Tags: economy, agriculture

https://hardware.slashdot.org/story/19/03/27/1851206/elizabeth-warren-calls-for-a-national-right-to-repair-law-for-tractors?sbsrc=md

> Farmers operating John Deere tractors have been fighting against John
>   Deere's repair monopoly for years. Device manufacturers don't want
>   people repairing their own stuff and they've taken pains to make it
>   difficult to do so. Newer John Deere equipment comes loaded with
>   software and firmware that make it impossible for farmers to fix their
>   own equipment. Instead, they have to call an authorized dealer and
>   wait for them to show up -- a fix that's too slow and too costly for a
>   farmer.

Why even buy a tractor (or other equipment) if you have this problem? I have not heard about this problem in EU, Canada and so on. Is this unique to America? Hence my question, why do American famers even buy tractors from John Deere?

Comment: The EU recently passed a law or regulation on [right to repair stuff](https://eeb.org/europe-paves-way-for-right-to-repair/). While tractors were probably not a top reason, there are similar issues in the EU, or any industrialized country. There are similar laws in at least some US states https://www.fastcompany.com/40518779/right-to-repair-legislation-has-now-been-introduced-in-17-states The devil is usually in the details with such laws.

Comment: How will you effectively farm on large scales without them?

Comment: @Obie2.0 There are other brands that may be more repair friendly.

Comment: I am not sure if this is really a question for experts in politics. Which brand of tractor to buy and why would be a question which needs to be answered by experts in agriculture. Unfortunately there is no agriculture stack exchange.

Comment: There's a strongly political element to it though Philipp, which is why I answered below.  There was a long fight to force companies to open up the specs of their phones (which consumers won), currently one going on to do the same for motor vehicles, and this is a small subset of that.  The question wasn't worded as a political question, but the underpinnings definitely are.

Comment: When anyone buys any product, they weigh the pros and cons.  This sort of "repair unfriendliness" would certainly be a con, but you seem to assume it is so severe that it outweighs any possible pros.  That's not so clear.  Maybe the John Deere tractor is 20% cheaper than the competing model, or 30% more reliable, or maybe it will harvest your crops 15% faster.  Those could certainly be valuable enough that you don't mind the tradeoff of having to call a repair technician to fix it when it does break down.

Comment: @NateEldredge Of course, but then this massive campaigning about how JD repair policy sucks is pretty weird. It would be like buying a Tesla and complain that they don't offer cars with ICE (or vice versa with a conventional car).

Comment: I suspect some of it is simply tradition, as with the car brands people buy.  "My daddy bought John Deere, my grandaddy bought John Deere, so I'm going to buy John Deere."  (My family always had GM cars when I was growing up, the first couple of cars I owned were GM, and if it hadn't been for the Chevy Vega, I might still be buying GM.)

Comment: The issue with devices being designed so you can't repair or maintain them yourself is true of all kinds of categories, from automobiles to coffee makers.  It's a common complaint of DIYers but the truth is most consumers still buy the products anyway.

Comment: @jamesqf Just so. My late father's first cousin collects John Deere tractors (he's an accountant, but the rest of the extended family on that side farms soybeans, corn and wheat in Northern Ohio), and I can't think of a single farmer in the extended family who doesn't own one of this dominant brand. The right to repair is a recent issue and the competition isn't on a par with the brand in reputation. A reduced need to repair matters more. If the only two brands available for your next car were Toyota and Yugo, would you buy a Yugo because you didn't like a Toyota repair or warranty policy?

Comment: Deere controls 53 percent of the U.S. market for large tractors and 60 percent of the U.S. market for farm combines. It also leads the used tractor market. https://blog.mascus.com/the-most-demanded-tractor-brands-on-the-used-equipment-market-during-the-first-half-of-2020/

Comment: This is an important topic and issue, and there certainly is some politics in it somewhere! I see it's been both well-received, upvoted and closed, which means it's *close to on-topic*. If you can find a way to adjust the question to be about politics it can be reopened, but maybe you can add a follow-up question based on some of these answers based on the political aspects of this, something like "Have any laws been proposed?" or "Are there any politicians championing laws...?" or "Why is it so hard to regulate... in the US?"

Comment: @uhoh: here's a point that is very much political: in a course about CE legislation I attended, someone from a university spin-off thought about including plans of their device (and using repair-friendliness as selling point). The trainer strongly discouraged this saying that would create substantial legal risk: making it easy to open a device (or, much worse, including drawings/plans of the mechanics or electronics) makes "repair" an intended use. Which means that the manufacturer is legally responsible that the device fulfils all kinds of work safety regulations not only when assembled...

Comment: ... but even when it's opened. Which is possible, but expensive. It is not legally possible over here (EU) to limit this liability by saying "open & repair at your own risk". He claimed that those weird types of screws used for devices fulfil a legal purpose rather than a mechanical one. Which is just to say that this problem isn't unique at all, and it may be difficult for buyers to find really repair friendly products because the competition may be only a bit less repair unfriendly.

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX yikes, I did't realize the challenges ran so deep! I hope this can be addressed somehow by modifying the question to get it reopened or by a new question getting asked.

Answer (score 9):

It required drilling down into these articles several layers (about 12) to find the relevant information.

First, the issue they complain about above only applies if the repair is with the computer itself.  If the issue is mechanical, you're more than welcome to fix it, or have someone else fix it.

John Deere is claiming that to "hack" the software locks would allow people to reverse engineer their proprietary software, which has been held to be true for other digital software, such as online games and tax software.

This is very similar to the fight over "Right to Repair" for motor vehicles, which would force car manufacturers to release all of the same information to anyone who wants to purchase it, as they do to their own, licensed service facilities. (This is a state issue, so that is broadly generalized as what the proposed laws actually require is different between states.)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motor_Vehicle_Owners%27_Right_to_Repair_Act

Slash Dot and Wired seem to be all over this, but their coverage appears to me, at least, to be a tad alarmist.

> But a big California farmers’ lobbying group just blithely signed away farmers’ right to access or modify the source code of any farm equipment software.

In 2018 California has proposed legislation for Right to Repair and a lobbyist group agreed to the following exemptions:
[image: Right to repair concession]

https://motherboard.vice.com/en_us/article/kz5qgw/california-farm-bureau-john-deere-tractor-hacking-right-to-repair

It is worth noting, for full disclosure, that the Clean Air Act actually requires electronic emissions monitoring and diagnostics for motor vehicles, so for cars, motorcycles, and buses at least, the option of just going to a car manufacturer that doesn't make onboard computers doesn't exist in the US.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_Air_Act_(United_States)

Answer (score 2):

It may be same as with other similarly restricted equipment:

- The marketing push obviously does not mention these problems, you need to research first, and the web is full of untrustworthy crap. The marketing information often tends to skip the "difficult" technical and practical parts as much as possible and jump right to conclusions ("this will boost your productivity do not ask us how").
- It may be difficult to estimate in advance which repairs would be more expensive and for how much, or that you may even need a new tractor when the company decides they just no longer support your current horse. The company may create more confusion by varying the price of repairs over time.
- Price, quality and prestige may still matter more. People still buy phones and laptops with useful ports removed on purpose, even if lack of them does not look for them exactly a "great feature".